# ros hydro runtime resouce localization

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I have a question regarding the basic knowledge about ros (especially hydro), which is, when the ros program starts, how does it locate the needed resources, e.g., libs, executables, etc. ?

Currently I install my ros in /opt/ros/hydro, and in hydro it seems that the source codes are not installed together any more. So if I want to make some changes to some ros pre-installed packages, e.g., ros navigation packages, I have to clone the source codes of the related packages in another directory (usually in the catkin workspace), and make changes and build them to get new libs or executables (so there are two ros packages with the same name now), then how could I make the program use the newly built libs without copying (or installing) them to replace the old ones in the ros install directory?

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70156/ros-hydro-runtime-resouce-localization/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0